# Prevent SwiftUI System Image from dynamically changing size for navigation bar item

Tags: ios, swiftui

I would like to add a plus button to the navigation bar items using the system plus image in SwiftUI. However, I am unable to prevent the system image from scaling dynamically when the accessibility font changes.

How can I stop it resizing so it acts like a standard UINavigationBarButtonItem system plus button?

The accessibility feature of holding on to a navigation bar button for large font types also doesn't work like it does with UIKit.

Really frustrating that a potentially simple thing can't be done with SwiftUI and that accessibility hasn't been thought about. The SwiftUI tutorials profile bar button also doesn't work for large font sizes. (PS SwiftUI is the future)

Here was my attempt:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Stop + Bar Button resizing")
                    .lineLimit(nil)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Plus"))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                PlusNavigationButton()
            )
        }
    }
}

struct PlusNavigationButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        PresentationButton(
            Image(systemName: "plus")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 44, height: 44),
            destination: NewView())
    }
}
```

[image: Plus bar button image resizes dynamically]

Comment: I don't think you can stop it from being resized. The `.navigationBarItems` get resized automatically by the system to support dynamic fonts on iOS. Isn't that what it supposed to do though?

Comment: @Edward are you trying to reduce the size of the image in the navigation bar?

Comment: @Let's_Create yeah I am. I want it to behave like the system + bar button in UIKit. Perhaps I should just use that instead?

Comment: In the given code I was able to reduce its size by reducing the value for .frame(width: 25, height: 25)  Is this what you want ?

Comment: But you still need it to be at least 44 points by 44 points as recommended

Comment: You can't use UIViewRepresentable with a UIBarButtonItem so I think that the only way this could work is by using a UINavigationController. Any idea where I can report this bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should build what you exactly want. So if you want to use 16x16 image with some extra hitTest area, you can build like this:

```
var body: some View {
    PresentationButton(
        HStack() {
           Spacer()
           Image(systemName: "plus")
               .resizable()
               .frame(width: 16, height: 16)
           Spacer()
        }.frame(width: 44, height: 44),    
        destination: NewView()
    )
}
```

or if you like some space around your image and let it fill the rest, you can:

```
var body: some View {
    PresentationButton(
        Image(systemName: "plus")
            .resizable()
            .padding(14)
            .frame(width: 44, height: 44),  
        destination: NewView()
    )
}
```